# Why Class.forName('database driver')?

Tags: java, database, jdbc

Why

```
Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(strUrl, props);
```

instead of

```
dbConnection = EmbeddedDriver.connect(strUrl, props);
```

?

Isn't it more error-prone to specify a string, instead of a class name that can be checked by the compiler? I saw an example where the class name was obtained from configuration, but this seems to be the pattern that is used regardless of available alternatives.

Comment: One can be used to load driver dynamically and later you are hard coding the driver.

Comment: Actually neither solution should be used nowadays. See Elliott's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a JDBC 4.0 driver (and up), all you need is

```
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(strUrl, props);
```

per the [`DriverManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) javadoc,

> JDBC 4.0 Drivers must include the file META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver. This file contains the name of the JDBC drivers implementation of java.sql.Driver. For example, to load the my.sql.Driver class, the META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver file would contain the entry:
>
> my.sql.Driver
>
> Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName(). Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using Class.forName() will continue to work without modification.

Answer (score 3):

The first code snippet lets your program avoid a compile-time dependency on the `EmbeddedDriver` class. For example, you could put the `"org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"` string in your configuration file, and read it at run-time.

The second code snippet "bakes in" the dependency on the `EmbeddedDriver` class into the body of your program, making it impossible to switch the driver without recompiling your code.

> Isn't it more error-prone to specify a string, instead of a class name that can be checked by the compiler?

That is absolutely true. Specifying a Java string literal for the name of the driver class is not a proper way to go, because your program would not gain any flexibility from accessing the class by name.

Comment: But how often do you actually need to switch from one driver to another at runtime? And why?

Comment: @Tiiba In many projects on which I worked the database the program uses must be user-configurable. The same program must work with DBs from several vendors, without recompiling. The client tells us which DB he has, and we work with it. Clients have their own reasons for choosing one RDBMS over the other (they have in-house DBAs, they use other products by the same vendor, and so on). An ability to work with DBs from multiple vendors gave us competitive advantage.

Comment: Hmm... I guess I see what you're talking about. Some kind of Web hosting service that lets users create apps with their own databases? I gave you +1 internet for making sense.

(And then I'll find out that you made one sense and I got another.)

Comment: @Tiiba Out product was designed for enterprise deployment, where customers could pick the vendor of the database, but then we, not the customers, would create the database for use with our program. Customers would maintain the database - do backups, manage its storage, compress logs, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that if you use `EmbeddedDriver.connect` then the JVM will load the `EmbeddedDriver` class when the class containing the statement is initialized.  Among other things, if `EmbeddedDriver` is not found in your class path this will cause the program to fail, even though the `EmbeddedDriver` class would never actually be used.  (There are other reasons for wanting to delay resolving the class as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I think that was required in the first versions of JDBC to ensure that DriverManager had the driver class loaded when requesting the connection. Direct access to the driver class in the code would have required the availability of the driver JAR at compile time and it was not the desired behavior from JDBC API.