# sqlException error while connecting to database

Tags: java, mysql

I have downloaded MySQL driver connector for java and I add it to librairies of my project but an error occur while connecting to my database " No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql".

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer your question.  Post the code on how you're initializing the driver and the connection so we can help you out.

Comment: have you included the jdbc driver jar in your project. here is a [link](https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/) to the download

Answer (score -1):

In case the driver is not loaded, you can call the following statement before getting connection.

Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

Check the link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html

Comment: That also would return the same exception

Comment: Please explain...

Comment: If the class isn't on the classpath, this throws the same exception, and this line hasn't been needed for a long time https://stackoverflow.com/a/24657416/2308683

Comment: Kindly check the documentation link provided in my reply.

Comment: That code in the site is old